Difference in available Memory when running tests via IntelliJ or gradlew test
I have code that parses some prettly large files. Unfortunately the structure of the file requires me to load it all into memory at the same time.
I am developing my software via TDD, so I have placed some example files into my test resources. When running the tests individually everything works fine. I have attached the intellij profiler to see how much memory my test run consumes and it comes out to be around what I expected, around 12.5 GB. A lot, but okay.

Then I tried to just run all tests at once at the end to see if they all passed. Curiously they didn't and threw me a lot of OutOfMemory exceptions. This happened both, if I double-clicked "test" in the gradle sidebar

and when I tried to use the default gradle wrapper in a terminal.
> Task :sdd-tests:test
SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests > twoStepParser_loadsP050IfcFile_loadsIndexedPolygonalFaceWithVoidsCorrectly FAILED
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests.java:222
SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests > twoStepParser_loadsP050IfcFile_getsElementsByIdCorrectly FAILED
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests.java:148
SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests > twoStepParser_loadsP050IfcFile_noErrorOnMissingType FAILED
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests.java:173
SDDTwoStepParserCDGP050Tests > twoStepParser_loadsP050IfcFile_getsAllElementsCorrectly FAILED
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I then created a memory dump in the tests, which confused me even more. The contents are unsuspicious and the size of it is only about 16 KB. Thats basically nothing. And I am surely not trying to acquire 12 GB of memory in one JVM call.

The tests were able to pass in the intellij run config, so there must be some configuration problem with the tests running standalone. They were failing to run even in a terminal completely independent from IntelliJ.
I have tried to configure the gradle vm to get more memory by putting this into my gradle.properties but no luck:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16384m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tests that use virtually no memory, are running fine in all versions, so the test runner itself is working.
What config options are there to increase memory for the tests here. Somehow IntelliJ manages to get enough memory, why doesn't gradle?
